# Error in my class

Tags: java, android

I don't know why I'm getting this exception. In my chat App whenever I try to send message, my app crash.

See the error in Logcat below:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:25)
    at com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:14)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
```

Below is my MessageAdapter.java class where I'm getting this error in this line:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);
```

---

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private List<Messages> messagesList;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> messagesList) {
        this.messagesList = messagesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Messages messages = messagesList.get(position);
        holder.chatText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

  public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView chatText;
        public CircleImageView chatImage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chatText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatText);
            chatImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.changeImage);
        }

    }

}
```

message_single_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MessageSingleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatImage"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="98dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/message_text_background"
        android:text="Hello" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is (android:background="@drawable/message_text_background") cause the problem? This is in my drawable 24 directory with root element of shape.

In video, the guy made drawable directory and in drawable directory he made the new drawable file. But in my case I'm using latest version so drawable directory is also exist and when I click on drawable there is no option to create new drawable file, so I did in drawable 24.

Comment: The problem is in the xml file, as the log says

Comment: `#17: Error inflating class TextView` issue is in layout file line 17 share your layout with question

Comment: please post xml code?

Comment: Can you post the layout for `message_single_layout.xml`?

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: Is (android:background="@drawable/message_text_background") cause the problem? This is in my drawable 24 directory with root element of shape.

Comment: @JimmyTrivedi why don't you try it and see it for yourself? remove the line and see if it works.

Comment: yes that message_text_background is the problem but what is solution? drawable is already exist in latest version of AS. and my end message_text_background is in drawable 24

Answer (score 2):

i think `message_text_background` is the problem.

remove below line and check

```
android:background="@drawable/message_text_background"
```

your drawable not exist in that version

go to your app directory app/src/main/res and create drawable folder and paste your message_text_background in to it

Comment: In video, the guy made drawable directory and in drawable directory he made the new drawable file. But in my case I'm using latest version so drawable directory is also exist and when I click on drawable there is no option to create new drawable file, so I did in drawable 24.

Comment: that is your problem. you can go to your app directory app/src/main/res and create drawable folder

Comment: then copy message_text_background to this directory

Comment: if problem steel there send message_text_background code

Comment: yes that message_text_background is the problem but what is solution? drawable is already exist in latest version of AS. and my end message_text_background is in drawable 24.

Comment: drawable folder NOT drawable-v24 pay attention

Comment: Yes buddy, but you're saying create drawable folder and my question is it is exist by default and when I right click on that there is no option to create new drawable file like I'm getting in d 24 directory.

Comment: how it is possible!? ok can you take a picture from it? or from left side of android studio?

Comment: Hi, in 2017 AS it was possible to create new drawable folder because that time it was not exist by default, but in latest AS it is exist, you can right click and check yourself, even if I right click on res and create new mydrawable in drawable(main), I'll not get that new Drawable file option. That is coming only D v24

Comment: i am not sure you can do that!

Comment: You're not giving me proper solution.

Comment: If you're using latest AS version, you must able to relate my problem.

Comment: don't know why but that option is coming now.

Answer (score 0):

"my end message_text_background is in drawable 24"

your mobile SDK version is 24 or not.

if not then change text background

Comment: How to know? I'm using 6.0.1 API level 23

Comment: I have sent a pic with answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please make another background XML file and save them in the lowest version as shown in attached pic.
If you have again doubt please let me know I will again clarify you.

Comment: I already did that. Thanks again and can you help me for one more problem? Check here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288664/the-messages-arent-being-displayed-on-the-textview-even-though-they-are-getting)

Comment: I will get back to you soon with answer